# Google Cloud, which storage is better, key/value

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-memorystore

I need to store (for the each user action in the system) a pair of strings:
**TransId, DetailId**
and mainly I need to read this value, sometimes update and finally delete.

Data should be persistent available after system restart or other maintenance.

The easiest way is to use CloudSQL, but I am thinking about Memorystore with failover (standard, not basic).

Memorystore is suitable for key value storage, but rather for cache... (and probably more expensive in compare to CloudSQL)

So maybe ideal option is CloudSQL, and in case that better performance is needed (additional cache by Memorystore).

What do you think?

Comment: Have you considered firestore? It would work very well for your use case

Comment: I don't need mobile sync etc. (firebase feature). Datastore - I thought about this, but generally my data has the same format (structured), always 2 fields, and I feel better when I havr full ACID in this case

Comment: Firestore is an interesting solution, and according to the volume, can be free. The other solutions aren't free. So, an important part of your use case isn't present in the description: What are your latency constraint? X ms? XX ms? XXX ms? Which volume (number of entries and size of each entry)? And what would like to do at the end with these stored data?

Comment: something between X and XXms. Volume - hundreds of thousands, maybe millions records, each string ~ 20-30 signs, at the end - we will remove this data from db

Answer (score 1):

Price aside, your use case fits more neatly with Memorystore. From a technical implementation standpoint, you are likely to have a much easier time developing with it. *(Which IMO is well worth the increased cost.)*

An SQL solution will likely cost you less, but will add some headaches around management.

If you're looking for a cheap solution, and you're running your code from a managed VM, I'd suggest [storing your key/values in the machine's metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata). ***This is a hack / workaround and should not be used in enterprise settings.***

Comment: so to summary your answer, we can use SQL and Memorystore, each solution has advantages and disadvantages. I can't use machine metadata in my case